# does PIP supports playback of Ads if stream has it

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, avplayer, picture-in-picture

I'm not sure and hence asking - does PIP will play/support the Ads if the video stream has in it.
For the custom AVPlayer, can will PIP work the same way

Thanks

googled around and still looking for proper guide.

Comment: Try looking at an existing app that streams with ads, and see.

Comment: @komalc - I also could not find anything on apple document